# Redirect url JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, redirect

I am trying to access a jsp file from WEB-INF/JSP/A.jsp. But finding it bit complex to understand to it.

Can some one explain some thing on redirect url path? What should be the redirect path. Can I have a custom path like WEB-INF/MyHtml/AB.html

The below code is in Home.jsp file in WebContent folder. (WebContent->Home.jsp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=A.jsp">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to change the url "A.jsp" to "WEB-INF/JSP/A.jsp" but failed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is correct. All u need to do is place your jsp file A.jsp in the same folder or package as your AB.html is,  or you can change the url attribute in meta tag to "/JSP/A.jsp".

Comment: If you are ok with using jsp to redirect to another jsp, then you can use <jsp:forward page="A.jsp"/> in your AB.jsp file, this might be a solution if just redirection is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can run that page in browser, and you can see at programmer's console(chrome f12) that at which location your code is seeking for the resource, so that you can put your file accordingly.

Comment: It only works if A.jsp is in WebContent. I think it is not possible to access files in WEB-INF directly, because of security reason. It will be nice if you can help me with few examples.(like file inside WebContent and file to redirect in WEB-INF/JSP folder)